# Center responsive nav

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i'm trying to center my nav in a responsive design. When the viewport is stretched to about 900px, the 3 nav titles look off center to the rest of the content on the page. Does anyone of a way to fix this?

HTML:

```
<header>

  <div id="logo">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/logo_55x73.png" alt="StudioMed" />
    </a>
  </div>

    <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e4e4e4;
}

#logo {
    padding: 2.3em 1.1em 1.7em 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    text-align: center; 
}

nav li {
    font-size: 0.95em;
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.06em; 
    padding: 0 1%;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 122px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:767px) {

    header {
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #logo {
        float: left;
        width: 10%;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
        width: 22.1354166666667%;
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its always a good idea to use `dev tools` on chrome and `firebug` on firefox to understand margin/padding issues.

Comment: Here's a [free fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6hRg/) with your posted code (I added a dummy image replacing the logo). But... I see the menu properly center, but the logo goes to the left if you resize more than 767px... What's exactly the expected behavior, please?

Comment: Hi Arkana. The logo is supposed to align left as expected. I was expecting the rest of the nav to align to the center when resized, yet the more i resize the screen the more off center it appears in comparison to the rest of my content.

Comment: Won't the floated logo throw off the centering for the menu? The logo will push the menu to the right, no?

Answer (score 2):

Your UL may have some default padding on its left.
Try adding this to your CSS:

```
nav ul {
  ...
  padding: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cxNZZ/

---

**EDIT:**

The padding issue above did not seem to solve your issue.
Here is a different theory:

Each LI is the same width, but the text inside each LI may not be. That could cause the menu to appear to be off center, even though the LIs are centered.

[image: LIs with equal widths]

http://jsfiddle.net/d6hRg/1/

[image: LIs with variable widths, depending on content]

http://jsfiddle.net/d6hRg/2/

See what I mean?

Comment: Hi, i've already reset the styles in a base css file. I've gone and added the zero padding to the ul but nothing's changed.

Comment: thanks for the update. I'm not sure if thats the problem here. The link to the image will show what i mean, I've made the background of the links black for a clearer visual: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5687256/nav%20error.tiff

Comment: I see. Because the logo is floated left, I think it pushes the menu off-center to the right. That or the percentage widths/paddings do not add up to 100%. How about positioning the logo absolutely? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u5y6D/

Comment: I positioned the logo absolutely and it works! Thanks for all your help!